# Automated web form processing by means of a form model description

Tags: php, html, forms

often, I get asked to write a small mini application which basically presents a form and verifies certain values and conditions once submitted to the server.

Thus, I started to generalize the process.

Now, the app loads a YAML specification of the form and a generalized controller manages its processing: Presents an instructional welcome page, presents the form, receives and validates values. Finally, it hands over the verified result to the persistence layer and informs the user, that his data/request has been saved.

The YAML based approach could eventual lead to a solution, in which the client writes himself a form model - without knowing a programming language.

I wonder, if I reinvent the wheel. Does someone know of a standard solution?

Kind regards,

Stefan

Comment: I dont know of anythign standalon but the Form Framework in Symfony form works much like this only its based on a ORM model class (Propel or Doctrine) generated from YAML or the DB - then on top of that there is an administration generator that does basic crud for a model. Zend Framework also supports this to come degree by declaring configuration for forms in the configuration file. Cake, Rails, and Django all do something similar as well.

Comment: Thank you, @prodigitalson. I'll have a look. At least to get inspired, probably to stop and switch over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several form libraries out there that handle form generation and validation for you, i.e. [HTML_QuickForm2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2). All you need to do is storing the data into the database if the form validates.

I'm not aware of full form-database-storage solutions, though.